# Reading content in plain text file and if the content is pass then it should go to next processor in Apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to create a pipeline where a folder has one output text file of python script. If output text file content has 'Pass' word, pipeline should move further. If not it should terminate. How to proceed this with Apache nifi?

Tried getfile->splitext->ExtractText but it seems not to work with my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try GetFile -> RouteOnContent. If the entire content of the file is `Pass` you can set `Match Requirement` on RouteOnContent to `content must match exactly`. If it just contains `Pass` you can set it to `content must contain match`. Then add a user-defined property (let's call it `pass` for this example) with the value set to `Pass`. Then you can continue your flow using the `pass` relationship and auto-terminate the `unmatched` relationship, thereby dropping the FlowFiles that don't match your requirement.